# Gravityforms and validate function

Tags: php, wordpress

I use multi page gravity forms. The code below checks first page and I can't click `next` button because the field is in second page and its not valid correctly. I tried with  `$current_page == 2` but it doesn't work for me and I don't know why.

Peace of code below. It would be nice if someone could give me a helping hand

```
// validate 9 digit code
// change here to your form ID
add_filter('gform_validation_1', 'validate_code');
function validate_code($validation_result){
        // this assumes the code is entered in field one on your form
        // change this input_ number if it's a different field
        if(!is_code_valid($_POST['input_18'])) {

        $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;
        foreach($validation_result['form']['fields'] as &$field){
            // field 1 is the field where we want to show the validation message
            if($field['id'] == 18){
                $field['failed_validation'] = true;
                                $field['validation_message'] = 'The code you entered is invalid: please try again.';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $validation_result;
}

// use this function to validate codes
function is_code_valid($thiscode){
        // read all the codes in from the numbers.txt file
        // change the path here to the location of your file
        $codes = file('/htdocs/homepages/99/numbers.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
        foreach($codes as $code){
                // compare the entered code to all codes in the file until we find a match
                if($thiscode == $code){
                        return TRUE;
                }
        }
        // if we did not have a match and are out of codes, return FALSE
        return FALSE;
}

// doing this here because the redirect URL does not support variables or shortcodes
// change the 70 here to your form ID
add_filter('gform_confirmation_1', 'valid_invitation_confirmation', 10, 4);
function valid_invitation_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $lead, $ajax){
        // customize this URL - I send the code in the query string
        $success_url = get_bloginfo('url') . '/?code=' . $lead[1];
        $confirmation = array('redirect' => $success_url);
        return $confirmation;
}
```

Comment: which function is validation for your field, which is in second page ?

Comment: I added something like that:
`if(!is_code_valid($_POST['input_18']) && current_page == 2){
//code
}`

Answer (score 0):

As you've realized, you only want to validate the field when the form page that contains it is submitted. Here is how can you check for that:

```
if( $field['pageNumber'] == GFFormDisplay::get_source_page($form['id'] ) ) {
    // run your custom validation here
}
```

This would go inside the $fields foreach loop. You can see this in action on [one of my snippets](http://gravitywiz.com/require-all-columns-of-list-field/).